# redbeard-ios adding RBMultipleChoiceField-s to RBManagedFormSchema

Tags: redbeard-ios

I am trying to add RBMultipleChoiceFieldOptions to RBManagedFormSchema, but getting error.

> [RBMultipleChoiceField identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

I can't figure out, what i did wrong or forgot to implement for adding MultipleChoiceFields, my ViewController is RBMultipleChoiceFieldDelegate delegate.

```
 RBMultipleChoiceFieldOption *touOption1 = [[RBMultipleChoiceFieldOption alloc] initWithValue:@"TOU1" displayText:@"Agree to TOU"];

         RBMultipleChoiceFieldOption *touOption2 = [[RBMultipleChoiceFieldOption alloc] initWithValue:@"TOU2" displayText:@"Agree to TOU"];

        RBMultipleChoiceField *tou = [RBMultipleChoiceField new];
        tou.options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:touOption1, touOption2, nil];

        //

        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[ nameFieldSchema, surnameFieldSchema, emailFieldSchema, passwordFieldSchema, confirmPasswordFieldSchema, genderFieldSchema, dobFieldSchema, tou]];

RBManagedFormSchema *formSchema = [RBManagedFormSchema schemaWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithArray:items]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 potential issues:

1) You may not have the latest version of the Redbeard Framework. There was a breaking change that renamed the property `fieldName` -> `identifier`. The error you're seeing points to this being the issue.

2) You must provide identifiers for form fields. In your code I can see that `RBMultipleChoiceField *tou` does not have it's `identifier` property set prior to creating the `RBManagedFormSchema`. A random identifier will be assigned automatically, but as it's random you won't easily be able to retrieve the field value.

P.S. you may download the **Forms** sample from [here](http://redbeard.io/samples/tutorial-forms), it provides working examples.